# Why does the Live Connect SignInButton fail with an invalid redirect_uri?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, liveconnect, live-connect-sdk

I'm experimenting with Windows Phone apps and live connect. I have this control on my main page:

```
xmlns:live="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Live.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Live.Controls"

...

<live:SignInButton ClientId="[my client id, which I registered earlier today]"
                   Scopes="wl.signin wl.basic"
                   Branding="Skydrive"
                   TextType="SignIn"
                   SessionChanged="SignInButton_SessionChanged" />
```

Here is the handler for `SessionChanged`:

```
private async void SignInButton_SessionChanged(object sender, LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    ...
}
```

I debug my app using the Windows Phone emulator. When I click the Sign In button, I get this exception:

> The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The client application must be marked as 'mobile' or the value must be an absolute URL which matches the registered redirect URI.

I do not explicitly specify a `redirect_uri` anywhere. Why does Sign In fail due to an invalid `redirect_uri`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must explicity mark your app as 'mobile' in the Windows Store Dev Center.

1. Open https://account.live.com/developers/applications/ in your browser.
2. Select your app from "My Applications"
3. Click the "Edit Settings" link
4. Click the "API Settings" link.
5. Set "Mobile or Desktop Client App" to "Yes".

[image: API Settings page screenshot]

Comment: This setting no longer seems to exist. How would one do this now?